# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or ' with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I'm working on creating a prepared PDO statement and executing it on a site, but I am getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or ' error. Please see my code below:

```
$STH = $DBH->('INSERT INTO model (x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?)');
$STH->bindParam(1, $x);
$STH->bindParam(2, $y);
$STH->bindParam(3, $z);
$name = $_GET['x'];
$ref_cat_id = $_REQUEST['y'];
$ref_man_id = $_REQUEST['z'];
$STH->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a prepared statement like:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO model (x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?)');
           //^^^^^^^See here
```